# Changing an objects on through C# script in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, android, gameobject

I am trying to export my Unity project to Android Studio so that I can create some Android buttons that "controls" the Unity app's behavior. I know what I have to do in order to let it access through Java, but I don't know how to change the color. I watched a video about on Youtube, and the guy used: `gameObject.renderer.material.color`. However, when I try to do the same it can't find material.

This is my script so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void ReceiveRotDir(string message)
    {
        if (string.Equals(message, "G"))
        {
            this.gameObject.renderer.m ///It can't find material
        }
        else if (string.Equals(message, "P"))
        {

        }
        else if (string.Equals(message, "B"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnHamilton, we do not accept duplicates across sites. Your links are for Stack Overflow, not GameDev.

Comment: @Gnemlock still it shows lack of research. Just looking at the docs (not even requires any thinking) is enough to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing "renderer" you need to actually reference the renderer component you are targeting.

For example:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color
```

Comment: so like this? `gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color(Color.black);`

Comment: No, that would not compile.  Color is not a function it is a property.

Comment: gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color‌​.black;

Comment: Yep, you got it.  Make sure you are targeting the proper renderer type for your gameobject.

Comment: How do I do that I am targeting the proper renderer type? The gameobject has a mesh renderer

Comment: Then you are targeting the right renderer type. I meant to say make sure you are targeting the proper "Component" type.